# Getting false notification for Review

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I am seeing notification count as 2 for review process, but when I click on it, it shows "The queue has been cleared", the count keeps showing as 2.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't a realtime metric.  It is [cached](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237845/wrong-posts-number-on-review-section) and rarely exact.

Comment: Thanks @MPD
http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3184006#3184006
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238472/review-count-fix-it-or-lose-it/238515#238515

Comment: @arpitr Thanks for digging up the link.  I added the canonical reference about this behavior.